# Encode number to a result

Tags: algorithm, math

In my app I need to run a 5 digits number through an algorithm and return a number between the given interval, ie:

The function encode, gets 3 parameters, 5 digits initial number, interval lower limit and interval superior limit, for example:
int res=encode(12879,10,100) returns 83.

The function starts from 12879 and does something with the numbers and returns a number between 10 and 100. This mustn't be random, every time I pass the number 12879 to the encode function must always return the same number.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Direz

Comment: You should check out hashing algorithms.

Comment: Can `encode()` return the same value for two different inputs?

Comment: @Blender: No... each input should return a single number between the given interval

Comment: @Direz: You're kinda contradicting yourself here. There *has* to be a pair of values which does this, as your output range is smaller than your input range.

Comment: @Blender: I'm sorry... What I need is this. Given a 5 digits number, return a unique result between the given interval... Is this possible? Why there has to be a pair of number? Why a pair?

Comment: @Direz: At least two. I'd say a few thousand with your constraints. Think of it like this. You have only `min - max` possibilities for output numbers. Your input numbers are ranging from `10000 -> 99999`, which means that there are `89999` input numbers. For every input number, there is a corresponding output number, right? But what if you have only `100 - 10` output numbers? Your function will still map every number to *one* of those `90` numbers, but you can't map `89999` numbers to `90` numbers. [Relevant Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection).

Comment: @Blender: yes, I get it now... I must think of something else. Please, read my comment to LBushkin's answer.

Comment: Based on your requirements your function `encode(a,b,c)` could just return `b` for every value of `a`! If that's too simple, then return `a % (c-b) + b` which is just a simple hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach:

1. compute the range of your interval R = (100 - 10) + 1
2. compute a hash modulo R of the input H = hash(12879) % R
3. add the lower bound to the modular hash V = 10 + H

Here the thing though - you haven't defined any constraints or requirements on the "algorithm" that produces the result. If all you want is to map a value into a given range (without any knowledge of the distribution of the input, or how input values may cluster, etc), you could just as easily just take the range modulo of the input *without* hashing (as Foo Bah demonstrates).

If there are certain constraints, requirements, or distributions of the input or output of your `encode` method, then the approach may need to be quite different. However, you are the only one who knows what additional requirements you have.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you're saying. Let me explain why I need this function (not for DNA sequence): 
In this game I'm trying to develop, the player turns 5 knobs and  composes a five digits number.
Then, I wanted to run this number through the encode function to size it down to the number of prizes that the prizes database holds.
For example, my database has 100 entries with prizes, sorted by value; suppose the first 10 are the less valuable, the next 10 more valuable, and so forth.
As the player levels up, the prizes are more valuable, hence the limit interval of the encode function...

Comment: So let me see if I understand. You want to map a random, 5-digit number to a certain range. The range will change over time (as the player levels up) so that prizes with higher values are accessible. You also want the prize selection to be deterministic (the same 5-digit number always yields the same prize). Yes? If so, then you have a potential problem in your requirements - namely that as the range interval changes, the same input will now map to a different "prize". If this does not matter to you, then the approach I describe should work. If I've misunderstood, something please clarify.

Comment: Yes, that's it.
I'm thinking, after reading all these comments and suggestions  (wich I thank), of using your method.
Now I dont mind that different numbers return the same result. I guess that it's inevitable...
I would like to be sure, though, that there is at lest one number that maps to each prize. Will the following function eventually returns all numbers of my interval?
(pseudo code)
for i = lower, i < upper
for j = 1 to 99999
return = lower + j % (upper-lower+1)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something simple like

```
encode(x,y,z) --> y + (x mod (z-y))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an upper limit for this function?

Assume it is 99999 because it is 5 digits. For your case, the simplest way is:

```
int encode (double N,double H,double L)
{
   return (int)(((H - L) / （99999 - 10000)) * (N - 10000) + 10);
}
```